# Taurus JSON Body post

Tags: performance, rest, jmeter, blazemeter, taurus

I trying to use taurus and test my restapi.
My restapi using JSON body in POST requests.
So i can't find anywhere how to put json into my POST request.

I tryed like this, but this not work.

```
execution:
  - concurrency: 25
    throughput: 25
    ramp-up: 1m
    hold-for: 5m
    steps: 3
    scenario: blazemeter-recording

scenarios:
  blazemeter-recording:
    timeout: 5s
    retrieve-resources: false
    store-cache: true
    store-cookie: false
    default-address: https://someurl
    headers:
      User-Agent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36'
      Accept-Language: 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4'
      Accept-Encoding: 'gzip, deflate, sdch'
      Accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp'
    requests:
      - url: '/api/v8/url/url/url'
        method: POST
        label: '/api/v8/url/url/url'
        headers:
          Content-Type: application/json
        body:
          "{\"applicationId\":1,\"objectId\":196,\"tags\":[{\"tag\":\"#ObjectsFilter:filter:Data#\",\"objectId\":196,\"pagination\":{\"pageSize\":100}}]}"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found solution, i can use "body-file"

```
      - url: 'url'
        method: POST
        label: 'data label'
        headers:
          Content-Type: application/json
        body-file: /var/tests/json_event_filter.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration is just fine, looking into [Taurus JMeter Executor HTTP Requests documentation](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#HTTP-Requests)

```
body: 'request-body-string'  # if present, will be used as body
```

You can double check it by [running Taurus in GUI mode](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Open-JMeter-GUI) like:

```
bzt your-test.yaml -gui
```

or

```
bzt -o modules.jmeter.gui=true your-test.yaml
```

You should see that [HTTP request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler has your JSON payload in the "Body Data" tab:

[image]

More information: [Navigating your First Steps Using Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/navigating-your-first-steps-using-taurus/)